# How do I return no rows when condition met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search a database for cases where they have been open 14 days, but have not been called.  I check in the steps for the word call, and can return the steps (without the word call).

I want to NOT return the case, if the work call exists (rather than returning the individual steps where the word call does not exist).

```
SELECT
    Support_Incident.Support_Incident_Code,
    Support_Incident.Company_Name,
    Support_Incident.Support_Incident_Name,
    Support_Incident.Severity,
    Support_Incident.MF_Status_Display,
    Support_Incident.MF_Action_Owner_Display,
    Support_Step.Description,
    DATEDIFF(hh, Last_Updated, GETDATE()) AS 'Main'
FROM 
    Support_Incident
INNER JOIN Support_Step
    ON Support_Incident.Support_Incident_Id = Support_Step.Support_Incident_Id
    AND (Support_Step.Description NOT LIKE '%phone%'
    AND Support_Step.Description NOT LIKE '%call%')
INNER JOIN Employee
    ON Employee.Employee_Id = Support_Incident.Owner_Id
WHERE 
    (DATEDIFF(hh, Support_Incident.Display_Create_Date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 336 AND 359
AND Support_Incident.MF_Action_Owner_Display <> 'Update'
AND Support_Incident.MF_Status_Display <> 'Closed'
AND Support_Incident.MF_Status_Display <> 'Defect'
AND Support_Incident.MF_Status_Display <> 'Enhancement'
AND Employee.Rn_Descriptor = '::sName');
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's an external tool that executes Odbc commands directly to the ODBC DSN.  However thinking you may be on to something, I just tried executing it in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio - same result - I get all the steps that do not contain the phrase, where I want none returned if one of the steps contains the phrase...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have

> (Support_Step.Description NOT LIKE '%phone%' AND Support_Step.Description NOT LIKE '%call%')

in the join statement and not in your where clause?

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    Inc.Support_Incident_Code,  
    Inc.Company_Name,  
    Inc.Support_Incident_Name,  
    Inc.Severity,  
    Inc.MF_Status_Display,  
    Inc.MF_Action_Owner_Display,  
    Step.[Description],  
    DATEDIFF(hh, Last_Updated, GetDate()) AS 'Main' 
FROM  
    Support_Incident AS Inc 
    INNER JOIN Support_Step AS Step ON Inc.Support_Incident_Id = Step.Support_Incident_Id 
    INNER JOIN Employee AS Emp ON Emp.Employee_Id = Inc.Owner_Id  
WHERE 
    (DATEDIFF(hh, Inc.Display_Create_Date, GetDate()) BETWEEN 336 AND 359  
    AND Inc.MF_Action_Owner_Display <> 'Update'  
    AND Inc.MF_Status_Display <> 'Closed'  
    AND Inc.MF_Status_Display <> 'Defect'  
    AND Inc.MF_Status_Display <> 'Enhancement'               
    AND Emp.Rn_Descriptor = '::sName'  
    AND step.[description] Not Like '%call%');
```

Comment: Style-wise, a good question, but since it's an INNER JOIN, it won't actually make any difference to the result, because the conditions in the ON clause must be true for all rows returned anyway. (If it was an outer, i.e. LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, there would be a significant difference.)

Comment: ok, so best to use something like: "AND inc.support_incident_code not in (select inc.support_incident_code from step where step.[description] like %call%)" in the where clause instead?

Comment: Thanks for you help - my code certainly looks a lot better structured now! :)  To answer your question, I only had it in the join as I was playing with ideas I found here of using NOT EXISTS in the join, but it didn't help, and as you rightly said, it makes no diference to the result.

Comment: Unfortunetely, the code still returns all steps that do not contain call...

    WHERE 
    (DATEDIFF(hh, Inc.Display_Create_Date, GetDate()) BETWEEN 336 AND 359  
    AND Inc.MF_Action_Owner_Display <> 'Update'  
    AND Inc.MF_Status_Display <> 'Closed'  
    AND Inc.MF_Status_Display <> 'Defect'  
    AND Inc.MF_Status_Display <> 'Enhancement'               
    AND Emp.Rn_Descriptor = '::sName'  
    AND inc.support_incident_code not in (select inc.support_incident_code from Support_Step where step.[description] like '%call%'));

Comment: Danny - Try putting the last where clause outside of the (). i.e. so you'll have two separate where clauses.

Comment: So that would just be moving the bracket, like this (if so, same result):

    'AND Emp.Rn_Descriptor = '::sName')  
    AND inc.support_incident_code not in (select inc.support_incident_code from Support_Step where step.[description] like '%email out%') '

Comment: hmmm, failing that the only other suggestion I can offer is to swap the "not in" and "in" i.e. AND inc.support_incident_code **in** (select... **not** like '%email out%')